# Issue DateTime.ToString with string format "M" in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, datetime-format

I have a problem with the string format of DateTime. I think it is bug in MS. Can you explain it, and what is wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("M"));//return 07 July   <---- WRONG, SEE MSDN
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(".M"));//return .7   <---- GOOD
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#M_Specifier)

Comment: I tried change to Invariant, en-US, cs-CZ it is same problem.

Comment: _"I think it is bug in MS"_ - this should [**never** be your first assumption](http://www.icodeguru.com/dotnet/debugging-strategies-for-.net-developers/8217final/LiB0010.html).

Comment: You have right about "I think it is bug in MS", sorry.

Comment: If you're just after the number of the Month, just use `DateTime.Now.Month;`.

Comment: I cannot use DateTime.Now.Month, I put as a parameter M or MM from another value.

Comment: Why can you not use this method? You seem to be trying to get the value to return as `7`, basing this on previous answers and comments. Unless this is a cultural related issue then that is exactly what `.Month` should give you. Because using `%M` will (unless a culture related issue) will `return 7`.

Comment: Input value is M or MM it depends on user action and I need return: 7 or 07 --> toString( "M" or "MM" ).

Comment: Fair enough, just more of a curiosity than anything.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [The `"M"` Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier)

> **If the "M" format specifier is used without other custom format
>   specifiers**, it is interpreted as the [`"M"` standard date and time format
>   specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MonthDay). For more information about using a single format specifier,
>   see [Using Single Custom Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers) later in this topic.

From [Using Single Custom Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers)

> A custom date and time format string consists of two or more
>   characters. Date and time formatting methods interpret any
>   single-character string as a standard date and time format string. If
>   they do not recognize the character as a valid format specifier, they
>   throw a `FormatException`. **For example, a format string that consists
>   only of the specifier "h" is interpreted as a standard date and time
>   format string. However, in this particular case, an exception is
>   thrown because there is no "h" standard date and time format
>   specifier.**
>
> To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as the only
>   specifier in a format string (that is, to use the "d", "f", "F", "g",
>   "h", "H", "K", "m", **"M"**, "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/" custom format
>   specifier by itself), **include a space before or after the specifier,
>   or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the single custom
>   date and time specifier**.

That's why you can use one of these;

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(" M")); // 7
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("M ")); //7
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("%M")); //7
```

Comment: +1. That's what I call reading between the lines. Everything was in front of OP. OP even provided the link.

Comment: +1. Thanks, this is the solution. Put % in "%M" return correct value.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: I think it is more just "reading the lines" than reading between the lines. ;-)